# Can not outsource UICollectionViewDatasource in extra class

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit

I have a ViewController with a CollectionView and would like to put the UICollectionViewDataSource in an extra-class, so that it can be reused. (I'm not using the interface builder).

Therefore, I created an extra-class:

```
class MyDataSource:  NSObject, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

        public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return 5
        }

        public func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }

        public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MYIDENTIFIER", for: indexPath)
            cell.backgroundColor = .blue
            return cell
        }

}
```

In the ViewController with the CollectionView, I set it:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MYIDENTIFIER")

    let myDataSource = MyDataSource()
    collectionView.delegate = myDataSource
    collectionView.dataSource = myDataSource

}
```

However, the collectionView will stay empty - there are no cells on it.

However, if I put all the DataSource Functions into the ViewController class itself and set the delegate and DataSource to **self**, then everything works.

Is it not possible to outsource the UICollectionViewDataSource in other files, or is there anything more you have to do?

Comment: I think you have to init the dataSource with a collectionView. Make an `init(collectionView: UICollectionView)` init in your dataSource class

Comment: @GaloTorresSevilla and how is it supposed to help?

Comment: @AndreyChernukha it will init the dataSource with the collectionView. Then you set the `collectionView.dataSource = self` in the dataSource class. I have done it that way and it has worked.

Comment: @GaloTorresSevilla and what is the actual difference between what is done and what you're suggesting? either way the collection view receives the datasource

Comment: Really not sure. That's why I say I think. I'll try to find out though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the help! I tried what Galo suggested, but for me this didn't work. However, I found the solution:

You have to initialize the delegate as property of the ViewController, and **not** in its viewDidLoad function! Then everything is working correctly!

```
let myDataSource = MyDataSource()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MYIDENTIFIER")

    collectionView.delegate = myDataSource
    collectionView.dataSource = myDataSource

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case. Here is the reason I was saying about calling the init method. @Andrey Chernukha, sorry if it caused any confusion. This is why I said that it works with the `init` but I guess it is the same reason as Pascal

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var collectionView : UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.backgroundColor = .green
        return cv
    }()

    var dataSource : CustomDataSource!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.view.addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
        dataSource = CustomDataSource(collectionView: collectionView)
    }

}

class CustomDataSource : NSObject, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    let collectionView : UICollectionView

    init(collectionView: UICollectionView) {
        self.collectionView = collectionView
        super.init()
        self.collectionView.dataSource = self
        self.collectionView.delegate = self
        self.collectionView.register(Cell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = .red
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
    }

}


class Cell : UICollectionViewCell {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
    }

    func setupViews() {
        self.backgroundColor = .red
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

I tested it and the reason is that `dataSource` is weak in a collectionView so it is deallocated immediately after it's instantiated if declared in `viewDidLoad()`

Answer (score 0):

It's another scope issue often been overlooked.

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MYIDENTIFIER")

let myDataSource = MyDataSource(). //See the problem here?
collectionView.delegate = myDataSource
collectionView.dataSource = myDataSource

} //myDataSource will be released!
```